# How can I implement WooCommerce REST API "orderby" successfully?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, api, woocommerce, sql-order-by

I'm creating a mobile application using flutter and I'm currently trying to list products with the ability to sort them, but everytime I try to implement the "orderby" parameter, I get this error:

```
I/flutter ( 5187): 
{
    "code":"rest_invalid_param",
    "message":"Invalid parameter(s): orderby",
    "data": 
    {
        "status":400,
        "params": 
        {
            "orderby":"orderby is not one of date, id, include, title, slug, price, popularity, and rating."
        },
        "details": 
        {
            "orderby": 
            {
                "code":"rest_not_in_enum",
                "message":"orderby is not one of date, id, include, title, slug, price, popularity, and rating.",
                "data":null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code where I get the error:

```
Future<List<Product>> getProducts({
    int pageNumber,
    int pageSize,
    String strSearch,
    String tagName,
    String categoryID,
    String sortBy,
    String sortOrder = "asc",
  }) async {
    List<Product> data = [];

    try {
      String parameter = "";

      if (strSearch != null) {
        parameter += "&search=$strSearch";
      }

      if (pageSize != null) {
        parameter += "&per_page=$pageSize";
      }

      if (pageNumber != null) {
        parameter += "&page=$pageNumber";
      }

      if (tagName != null) {
        parameter += "&tag=$tagName";
      }

      if (categoryID != null) {
        parameter += "&category=$categoryID";
      }
      if (sortBy != null) {
        parameter += "&orderby=$sortBy";
      }

      if (sortOrder != null) {
        parameter += "&order=$sortOrder";
      }

      String url = Config.url +
          Config.productsURL +
          "?consumer_key=${Config.key}&consumer_secret=${Config.secret}${parameter.toString()}";

      var response = await Dio().get(
        url,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = (response.data as List)
            .map(
              (i) => Product.fromJson(i),
            )
            .toList();
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.response);
    }

    return data;
  }
```

In a couple of other similar questions, I've been seeing that I need to add a filter looking like this:

```
add_filter( 'rest_product_collection_params', array( $this, 'filter_add_rest_orderby_params' ), 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'rest_product_cat_collection_params', array( $this, 'filter_add_rest_orderby_params' ), 10, 1 );

function filter_add_rest_orderby_params( $params ) {
    $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';
    return $params;
}
```

I wanted to try this, however, I'm not sure if this would work in my case, and does anyone know what specific file I am going to edit to add this filter? I can't seem to find where people put it. (I'm using Wordpress.)